# ARKit detecting intersection between planes

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, image-recognition

I am using ARKit (with Scene Kit) and am trying to find a way to get the intersection between an ARReference image and a Horizontal ARPlaneDetection to display a 3D character on the surface directly in front of the detected image, e.g., Spawn inside the red circle see image below

[image]

At the moment I am able to get the character to spawn in front of the detected image, however, the character is floating in the air instead of standing on the surface.

```
let realWorldPositon = SCNVector3Make(anchor.transform.columns.3.x, anchor.transform.columns.3.y, anchor.transform.columns.3.z)
let hitTest = self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.hitTestWithSegment(from: self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.worldPosition, to: realWorldPositon, options: nil)
overlayNode.position = SCNVector3Make((hitTest.first?.worldCoordinates.x)!, 0, (hitTest.first?.worldCoordinates.z)!) 
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(overlayNode)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[Example project](https://github.com/daniil-shumko/ARKitImageRecognition)

Comment: @JoshRobbins hey, your answer was correct, can you add it back in so I can mark it as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were on the right lines using the `hitTestWithSegment` function to detect an intersection between the `ARImageAnchor` and the `ARPlaneAnchor`.

Rather than trying to explain each step of my attempt at an answer, I have provided code which is fully commented, so it should be fairly self explanatory.

My example works fairly well (although its certainly not perfect) and will definitely need some tweaking.

For example, you will need to look at determining more accurately the distance from the `ARReferenceImage` to the `ARPlaneAnchor` etc.

I can get the model (a Pokemon) to place at the correct level and fairly close to the front of the `ARReferenceImage`, although it will need tweaking.

Having said this, I think this will be a fairly good base for you to start refining the code and getting more accurate results.

Of note however, is that I have just enabled one `ARPlaneAnchor` to be detected (just for simplicities sake) and have assumed that you will be detecting a plane infront of your image marker.

I haven't taken into account rotation or anything like that. And of course, based on your proposed scenario; it also assumes your image would be on a desk or some other flat surface.

Anyway, here is my answer (hopefully it should be fairly self explanatory):

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

//-----------------------
//MARK: ARSCNViewDelegate
//-----------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. If We Have Detected Our ImageTarget Then Create A Plane To Visualize It
        if let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {

            createReferenceImagePlaneForNode(currentImageAnchor, node: node)
            allowTracking = true

        }

        //2. If We Have Detected A Horizontal Plane Then Create One
        if let currentPlaneAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor{

            if planeNode == nil && !createdModel{ createReferencePlaneForNode(currentPlaneAnchor, node: node) }
        }

    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check To See Whether An ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Updated
        guard let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor,
              //2. Check It Is Our PlaneNode
              let existingPlane = planeNode,
              //3. Get The Geometry Of The PlaneNode
              let planeGeometry = existingPlane.geometry as? SCNPlane else { return }

        //4. Adjust It's Size & Positions
        planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
        planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

        planeNode?.position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, 0.01, anchor.center.z)
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        //1. Detect The Intersection Of The ARPlaneAnchor & ARImageAncho
        if allowTracking { detectIntersetionOfImageTarget() }

    }

}

//---------------------------------------
//MARK: Model Generation & Identification
//---------------------------------------

extension ViewController {

    /// Detects If We Have Intersected A Valid Image Target
    func detectIntersetionOfImageTarget(){

        //If We Havent Created Our Model Then Check To See If We Have Detected An Existing Plane
        if !createdModel{

            //a. Perform A HitTest On The Center Of The Screen For AnyExisting Planes
            guard let planeHitTest = self.augmentedRealityView.hitTest(screenCenter, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent).first,
                let planeAnchor = planeHitTest.anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

            //b. Get The Transform Of The ARPlane Anchor
            let x = planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.x
            let y = planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.y
            let z = planeAnchor.transform.columns.3.z

            //b. Create The Anchors Vector
            let anchorVector = SCNVector3(x,y, z)

            //Perform Another HitTest From The ImageAnchor Vector To The Anchors Vector
            if let _ = self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.hitTestWithSegment(from: imageAnchorVector, to: anchorVector, options: nil).first?.node {

                //a. If We Havent Created The Model Then Place It As Soon As An Intersection Occures
                if createdModel == false{

                    //b. Load The Model

                   loadModelAtVector(SCNVector3(imageAnchorVector.x, y, imageAnchorVector.z))

                    createdModel = true

                    planeNode?.removeFromParentNode()

                }
            }
        }
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //1. Reference To Our ImageTarget Bundle
    let AR_BUNDLE = "AR Resources"

    //2. Vector To Store The Position Of Our Detected Image
    var imageAnchorVector: SCNVector3!

    //3. Variables To Allow Tracking & To Determine Whether Our Model Has Been Placed
    var allowTracking = false
    var createdModel = false

    //4. Create A Reference To Our ARSCNView In Our Storyboard Which Displays The Camera Feed
    @IBOutlet weak var augmentedRealityView: ARSCNView!

    //5. Create Our ARWorld Tracking Configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    //6. Create Our Session
    let augmentedRealitySession = ARSession()

    //7. ARReference Images
    lazy var staticReferenceImages: Set<ARReferenceImage> = {

        let images = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: AR_BUNDLE, bundle: nil)
        return images!

    }()

    //8. Scrren Center Reference
    var screenCenter: CGPoint!

    //9. PlaneNode
    var planeNode: SCNNode?

    //--------------------
    //MARK: View LifeCycle
    //--------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //1. Get Reference To The Center Of The Screen For RayCasting
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.screenCenter = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.height/2) }

        //2. Setup Our ARSession
        setupARSessionWithStaticImages()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }

    //---------------------------------
    //MARK: ARImageAnchor Vizualization
    //---------------------------------

    /// Creates An SCNPlane For Visualizing The Detected ARImageAnchor
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor
    ///   - node: SCNNode
    func createReferenceImagePlaneForNode(_ imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor, node: SCNNode){

        //1. Get The Targets Width & Height
        let width = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
        let height = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

        //2. Create A Plane Geometry To Cover The ARImageAnchor
        let planeNode = SCNNode()
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
        planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
        planeNode.opacity = 0.5
        planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry

        //3. Rotate The PlaneNode To Horizontal
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

        //4. The Node Is Centered In The Anchor (0,0,0)
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        //5. Store The Vector Of The ARImageAnchor
        imageAnchorVector = SCNVector3(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.x, imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.y, imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)

        let fadeOutAction = SCNAction.fadeOut(duration: 5)
        planeNode.runAction(fadeOutAction)

    }

    //-------------------------
    //MARK: Plane Visualization
    //-------------------------

    /// Creates An SCNPlane For Visualizing The Detected ARAnchor
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - imageAnchor: ARAnchor
    ///   - node: SCNNode
    func createReferencePlaneForNode(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, node: SCNNode){

        //1. Get The Anchors Width & Height
        let width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
        let height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

        //2. Create A Plane Geometry To Cover The ARImageAnchor
        planeNode = SCNNode()
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
        planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
        planeNode?.opacity = 0.5
        planeNode?.geometry = planeGeometry

        //3. Rotate The PlaneNode To Horizontal
        planeNode?.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

        //4. The Node Is Centered In The Anchor (0,0,0)
        node.addChildNode(planeNode!)

    }

    //-------------------
    //MARK: Model Loading
    //-------------------


    /// Loads Our Model Based On The Resulting Vector Of Our ARAnchor
    ///
    /// - Parameter worldVector: SCNVector3
    func loadModelAtVector(_ worldVector: SCNVector3) {

        let modelPath = "ARModels.scnassets/Scatterbug.scn"

        //1. Get The Reference To Our SCNScene & Get The Model Root Node
        guard let model = SCNScene(named: modelPath),
              let pokemonModel = model.rootNode.childNode(withName: "RootNode", recursively: false) else { return }

        //2.Add It To Our SCNView
        augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pokemonModel)

        //3. Scale The Scatterbug
        pokemonModel.scale = SCNVector3(0.003, 0.003, 0.003)

        pokemonModel.position = worldVector

        augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pokemonModel)


    }

    //---------------
    //MARK: ARSession
    //---------------

    /// Sets Up The AR Session With Static Or Dynamic AEImages
    func setupARSessionWithStaticImages(){

        //1. Set Our Configuration
        configuration.detectionImages = staticReferenceImages
        configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

        //2. Run The Configuration
        augmentedRealitySession.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])

        //3. Set The Session & Delegate
        augmentedRealityView?.session = augmentedRealitySession
        self.augmentedRealityView?.delegate = self

    }

}
```

Hope it points you in the right direction...